# function template specialization compile error

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

```
##A.hh

template<class T> void func(T t) {}
template<> void func<int>(int t) {}

void func2();

##A.cpp

void func2() {}

##main.cpp

func("hello");
func(int());
```

The error I get is:  error LNK2005: "void __cdecl func(int)" (??$func@H@@YAXH@Z) already defined in A.obj, 
one or more multiply defined symbols found

Is a function template specialization not treated as a normal function template? It looks like it will be in the objective file for A.

Comment: What does `func2` have to do with it?

Comment: From your error message I assume you use VC. Your program works fine for me on VS2005

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y So I had something to put in the A.cpp file

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As `template<> void func<int>(int t) {}` is a function overload rather than a function template (i.e., all types are known at the point of definition so it is no longer a template), it must be marked as `inline` or defined in a .cpp file to avoid multiple definition errors, just as with any other function definition.

Comment: But if its treated as a normal function, what is then the difference with an overloaded function: inline void func(int t) {}

Comment: @hidayat : Overload resolution precedence is the only difference -- non-templates are always preferred over templates (see 13.3.3). This is covered in detail in the book 'More Exceptional C++' by Herb Sutter.

Answer (score 16):

The problem is as follows: full template specialization is no more a *template*, it's more like an *ordinary function*. So you should act accordingly:

- either put definition of `func<int>()` in cpp file
- or make it inline