# How to get rid of multiple definitions of fully specialized function templates?

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries

I'm having a problem with linking the objects of one of my C++ applications. The source files are all compiled into object files, but many of them rely on the same library, which has a fully specialised function template. The linker complains when trying to link them all together. I understand why this is, but I *don't* understand how to fix it.

I found [this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t290309-fully-specialized-function-template-and-multiple-definition.html), which explains the problem exactly, but the forum thread never got to a point where the OP asked for a solution. Womp, womp.

How do I compile all the source files, but only get the specialised functions from the library once?

Comment: possible duplicate of [function template specialization compile error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417215/function-template-specialization-compile-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem there is that the specialization also has the implementation in the header, which is wrong.

You should either move the implementation to a source file, or mark the method as `inline`.

Comment: I was under the impression (according to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039/templates-spread-across-multiple-files) that one should not spread template information across multiple files. Therefore inlining is the only way? Not that I have a problem with that--just trying to make sure I understand fully.

Comment: @TomThorogood if you specialize something, you're not really working with a template anymore. A specialized template is already a class or a function. An un-specialized template is just a rule (or a skeleton) for the compiler to build an actual class or function by (on).